# How get root in Stylus?

Tags: nested, root, stylus, bem

I have problem with root nesting

for better work with bem-modules in **Sass** we are use `$root`

```
.block
  $root: &
  background: gray
  &__elem
    background: red
    color: black
  &:hover
    #{$root}__elem
      color: white
```

this code compiled to:

```
.block {
  background: gray;
}
.block__elem {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}
.block:hover .block__elem {
  color: white;
}
```

**How get this effect in stylus?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stylus have a special selectors for the same case.

[stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#initial-reference](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#initial-reference)

You can use `~/` or `^[0]`

```
.block
    &:hover
        ~/__elem
            color: white
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов Probably this is an old version. Try this - http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.block%0A%20%20background%20gray%0A%20%20%26__elem%0A%20%20%20%20background%3A%20white%0A%20%20%20%20~%2F%3Ahover%20%26%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3A%20blue

Comment: what if we use @extend?

Comment: `.element` > `&--modifier` > `@extend ^[0]` — not working

Comment: `.element` > `&--modifier` > `@extend ~/` — and this not work

Comment: in this ^ examples — we need to get styles of `element` in `.element--modifier`

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов is that contrary to the methodology of BEM.

Comment: block may have modifier, with same properties. i confused and write `element` instead `block`

Comment: and so we need: `.block` > `&--modifier` > `@extend ^[0]` (.block style has modifier with root style, and their special style)

Comment: this alternative for sass: `.block` > `$root: &` + `&--modifier` > `@extend #{$root}`

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов still contrary to the methodology of BEM.The modifier should not contain block style. Only overwrites. You may use mixins

Comment: Oo )) ... [whats wrong?](http://codepen.io/AliveDD/pen/oLWzoZ?editors=0100) — it is very clean and clear

Comment: mixins working too, but have the worst readability and the number of code lines in css is [increased from 30 to 56](http://codepen.io/AliveDD/pen/YWVGva?editors=0100)

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов That's wrong way. It must be — `class="status status--ok"` This is true according to the methodology. What if you want to use several modifiers? Like `class="status status--err status--big status--withoutborder"`